# Jquery - Hide a Div(A) when the page is scrolled to the start of another div(B) which have a ID

Tags: jquery

There is a Fixed Div(A) at the bottom, when the page scrolls to the footer which have a id="Footer", the Div(A) Should hide.

```css
        .fixDiv {
            padding: 10px;
            background: yellow;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 5%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
        #div1,
        #div2,
        #div3 {
            height: 500px;
        }
        #footer {
            height: 100px;
            background: red;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="fixDiv">HELLO</div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I mean you could just add `position:relative` to `#footer`...

Comment: Im trying to hide the div with the class="fixDiv"  when it reaches the footer which have the id="footer". I need jquery to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried $(".fixDiv").css('z-index','-1'); ? The idea is for the fixed div to have a less z-index than the footer.

Comment: Im Trying to achieve this using jquery.

Comment: @ArjunPandi Why? Why use jQuery when CSS does the job perfectly fine? Why are you literally shooting yourself in the foot?